# Asymptotic behaviour of Fourier Series coefficients for discontinuous functions

Tags: real-analysis, continuity, fourier-series

I have seen the occasional reference in literature to the idea that a periodic function is discontinuous iff its Fourier series coefficients $ c_n $ are such that $ c_n \in \mathcal{O}(n^{-1}) $, but this has always been posited without any formal proof or further explanation.

I've tried searching for any further information about this idea, but haven't found anything. Am I being particularly slow, or is this a non-trivial result which requires further proof?

[image: From Signals, Sound, and Sensation By William M. Hartmann]

Comment: The theorem as you have stated it is false. You usually get growth restrictions on Fourier coefficients by making stronger continuity and smoothness assumptions, not the other way around. Perhaps you are confusing this with the theorem that a $C^1$ periodic function has Fourier coefficients $c_n = O(n^{-1})$?

Comment: If $f$ is periodic and discontinuous then its Fourier series coefficients cannot decrease faster than $\frac{1}{n}$, that is $\lim_{n \to \infty} \sup n |c_n| > 0 $

Comment: It is easy to show that if $\sum_n |c_n|  < \infty$ then the Fourier series converges uniformly and $f$ is continuous.

Comment: @Vik78 I've updated my question to include a screenshot with this 'theorem'.

Comment: Here "discontinuity" means a jump. This is different from "discontinuous" (for example $\sin(1/x)$ doesn't have a jump but it is not continuous). And what you quoted is unclear. They are probably talking of $c_n$, not $|c_n|$

Comment: @user1952009 Yes it's very unclear. I assumed discontinuity refered to any discontinuity (such as an essential discontinuity in the case of $\sin(1/x)$).